# nested return statements inside render method

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please explain to me this syntax of having nested return statements inside the render() method.

```
  render() {
    // TODO replace the <div> contents below with the copied portion of html
    return (
      <div id="layout">
          <h1 id="page-title">Express Todo</h1>
          <div id="list">

            <TodoInput create={this.create}></TodoInput>

            { this.state.todos.map( todo => {
                return (
                  <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} remove={this.remove}>
                  </TodoItem>
                )
            })}

          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This code actually renders all two components(TodoInput, TodoItem) correctly. I just want to understand the logic behind this.

TIA :)

Comment: Do yourself a favour, learn javascript fundamentals before jumping into frameworks and libraries.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, some people learn by doing :) And they might get confused sometimes. That's one of the reason forums like this exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `render` function here has only one return statement, the second one is a return statement of an anonymous function (lambda) provided as an argument to the `map` method of the `this.state.todos` array. So, one of the elements of what `render` here returns are the components returned by mapping `todos` array. Make sure you understand how `Array.map`, anonymous functions and React components work.